# Can I trigger events based on timestamp data or should I use polling?

Tags: sql-server, performance, trigger

I'm asking this question for SQL Server 2008+ but this could really be for any DBMS.

Imagine you have scheduled data, something like:

```
ID   Data   Timestamp
0    NULL   2014-11-22
1    ...    2014-11-24
2    ..     2014-11-25
```

Is there a way to trigger my application when a timestamp is reached ?
Or shouldn't I do this in the first place and use polling instead because of performance reasons just like with triggers when new rows are added ?

I think that in theory the 'trigger based on timestamp' seems much better than the 'trigger based on new row' concerning the performance because you can easily group rows together based on their timestamps.
However, I have absolutely no idea how to actually do this in practice.

FYI: I'm inexperienced with DBMS systems, so maybe I have overlooked something very obvious. Sorry in that case.

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger my application"? Is it an executable you want to run? A SQL script? Is it firing for every row? If so why do you want to group rows? Can you tell us more about the logic/scenario?

Comment: Your example shows dates. Not times. What  sort of volume do you expect. 1 row a day? Dozens? Thousands? How fast does your application need to respond? To the second? Is the nearest minute acceptable?

Comment: Independent of volume, I'd love to know whether it is possible at all. So let's assume I just want to trigger an external application and the volume is fairly low. That would only be the second part of the question (i.e. 'Is it intelligent to do this?')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is very similar to a question recently posted on S.O.: [Time trigger database updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980282/time-trigger-database-updating/26981484#26981484))

There is no *direct* way of doing this, at least not in SQL Server. In that similar question linked above I did detail a way of getting very close to this concept in SQL Server, and someone mentioned Service Broker, but these are still indirect and have not really been tested to see how well they meet up to the original desire.

On the other hand, I also mentioned in my answer in that other question that there is a technology that does do exactly this (i.e. time-based expiration): cache severs. There are at least three that I am aware of:

- [memcached](http://memcached.org/)
- [redis](http://redis.io/)
- [Microsoft AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh351318.aspx)

---

Or, depending on how this question is interpreted, if the desire is to kick off a process based on reaching a specific time, you can implement something like [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) which is a job scheduler. Using this you could still keep track of the schedules in a table in SQL Server, and when events get kicked off, part of that process would update that table in SQL Server with the status.

A simplistic, general setup might look like:

- `[ScheduleData]` table

  - Add `[StatusID] TINYINT`

    - Values:

      - 1 = Completed/Pending
      - 2 = Running
      - 3 = Error
  - Add `[ErrorCount] TINYINT`
  - Add DEFAULT CONSTRAINT on [ErrorCount] being `(0)`
  - Maybe rename [timestamp] field to be [CreatedOnDate] or [ModifiedOnDate]
  - Add DEFAULT CONSTRAINT on [CreatedOnDate] being `(GETDATE() or GETUTCDATE())`
  - Add `[TaskOutput] NVARCHAR(MAX)`
  - Add DEFAULT CONSTRAINT on [TaskOutput] being `('')`
- Stored Procedures:

  - `[ScheduleData_AddNewTask]`

    - Params (@Data NVARCHAR(4000 or MAX), @ScheduleDataID INT OUTPUT)
    - INSERT INTO dbo.ScheduleData (Data, StatusID) VALUES (@Data, 1);
    - SET @ScheduleDataID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
  - `[ScheduleData_UpdateTask]`

    - Params (@ScheduleDataID INT, @StatusID TINYINT, @TaskOutput NVARCHAR(MAX))
    - `UPDATE [ScheduleData]
      SET StatusID = @StatusID,
      TaskOutput = @TaskOutput,
      ErrorCount = [ErrorCount] + (CASE @StatusID WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      WHERE ScheduleDataID = @ScheduleDataID;`
- App code:

  - When you are creating a new job to be scheduled:
  - First, call `[ScheduleData_AddNewTask]` which returns `ScheduleDataID`
  - Create the job such that it will:

    - Start by calling `[ScheduleData_UpdateTask]`, passing in the `ScheduleDataID`, `2` for @StatusID, and `String.Empty` for @TaskOutput.
    - Finish by calling `[ScheduleData_UpdateTask]`, passing in the `ScheduleDataID`, `1` for @StatusID, and anything relevant for @TaskOutput.
    - If an error occurs, call `[ScheduleData_UpdateTask]`, passing in the `ScheduleDataID`, `3` for @StatusID, and anything relevant for @TaskOutput.

Comment: Thank you for that answer ! It's pretty much exactly what I was looking for. And sorry for the duplicate, I honestly spent an hour or so looking for this question but it seems like it's just not really a thing and so I couldn't really find the search terms to look for.

Comment: I already know Quartz.NET a bit but never really used it, so I'm not sure how to connect that to a database (so that the scheduled jobs can be logged to a database and reported on etc.). Can you point me to some documentation or example on how to do that ?

Comment: @MattKo No need to apologize for not finding that other question as it is poorly named and also not exactly what you are wanting. In fact, I will change the wording here to not state that it _is_ a duplicate. I don't know of any doc or examples, so I described how an implementation might go if I understand correctly what you are trying to do.

Comment: That's fine. I looked up the tutorial on Quartz's website  and it's pretty much exactly what I need. If I run into problems with that, I'll just ask a new question here or on SO depending what kind of problem it is :)

Comment: @MattKo Sounds good. Can you post the link to whatever example fit your needs and I can add it to my answer to make it easier to find for the next person?

Comment: There's not a single example that I found, but I think the tutorial in Quartz for persisting data in a DB would be a good source: http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/job-stores.html